# convert string to URL objective-C

Tags: objective-c, webview, url-encoding

I am creating a screen where user can input any text. Now that text has to be converted to a valid url. I have looked into lot of stack overflow question and they have come up with the fooling solution:
1. CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                            NULL,
                            (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                            NULL,
                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

2. Category on the string

```
- (NSString *)urlencode {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Example: If the user manually puts the required %20 (for example) in the text instead of white space and then if we use any of the above solution the %20 would be converting to %25.

Could anybody let me know how can I fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because `%` will be urlencoded to `%25`, actually the `%20` will be urlencoded to `%2520`, which is the desired output.

If you want to keep the `%20` in the user input, you can replace all the `%20` with a single white space, then urlencoded the replaced string.

Comment: That was one just example. How do I handle other? Is there anyway to handle such senaroies  and convert the string to valid url.?